# Do not display XML content when read using CURL in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, get

I want to retrieve XML data related to weather. 
For that i use this API for it.

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22Kandy%22)

I tried to di it with CURL in PHP

This is my code

```
$url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22Kandy%22)";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($xml);
```

But it retrieve blank output without any of text. Please help me to sortout this problem.

Comment: does `$data` empty ?

Comment: It seems to work. Did you `curl_init()`?

Comment: If that is your code ... where do you `curl_init()`??

Comment: yes it also a mistake. i got an answer from george and it worked. im new to this section actually. thanks all...

Comment: yes it also a mistake. i got an answer from george and it worked. im new to this section actually. thanks all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the cURL request like this:

```
   $url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22Kandy%22)";

    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

    $data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
    curl_close($ch);

    $xml = (array)simplexml_load_string($data);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($xml);
    echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: thank you very much. it worked for me. im new to this section.

Comment: i want to concatanate URL with variable in this progrm. but when i do it it do not retrive data as i expect. this is my url with concatanated variable  ($url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22{$city}%22)")

Comment: There might be something wrong with your `$city` variable. Make sure it is of type String. I set `$city="Chicago"` in your example and everything seems to work fine